# Only one circle is showing up, after running the following script. Why? How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I tried to "drow" several "boubles" on the canvas. I wrote this little script, but after running it, only one circle is showing up. It's seems like it is drawing tha same "bouble" 100 times. Why?

This is my app.js:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.98;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var boubles = [];

var createBouble = function() {
  this.x = width * Math.random();
  this.y = height * Math.random();
  this.color = getColor();
  this.radius = 30 + (Math.random() * 50);
//  console.log(this);
  return this;
}

var getColor = function() {
  return 'rgba(' + (Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + (Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + (Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + 0.3 + ')';
}

var generateBoubles = function(amount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    boubles.push(createBouble());
  }
  drowBoules();
}

var drowBoules = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < boubles.length; i++) {
    drowBouble(i);
  }
}

var drowBouble = function(index) {
  context.fillStyle = boubles[index].color;
  context.arc(boubles[index].x, boubles[index].y, boubles[index].radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

generateBoubles(10);
```

```html
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `createBouble` function you must return object of values and in `drowBouble` function you must first do `context.beginPath();`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.98;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var boubles = [];

var createBouble = function() {
  let x = Math.floor( width * Math.random());
  let y = Math.floor(height * Math.random());
  let color = getColor();
  let radius = 30 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

  return {x,y,color,radius};
}

var getColor = function() {
  return 'rgba(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + 0.3 + ')';
}

var generateBoubles = function(amount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    boubles.push(createBouble());
  }
  drowBoules();
}

var drowBoules = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < boubles.length; i++) {
    drowBouble(i);
  }
}

var drowBouble = function(index) {
  context.fillStyle = boubles[index].color;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(boubles[index].x, boubles[index].y, boubles[index].radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

generateBoubles(10);
```

```html
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the function

```
var createBouble = function() {
  this.x = width * Math.random();
  this.y = height * Math.random();
  this.color = getColor();
  this.radius = 30 + (Math.random() * 50);
//  console.log(this);
  return this;
}
```

When you `console.log` `this` it is always turning out to be the `window` object.

That is because it is being treated as a normal function.

You should use the `new` keyword when creating a new object.

i.e. it should be

```
var generateBoubles = function(amount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    boubles.push(new createBouble()); // use new here
  }
  drowBoules();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `createBouble()` without any binding to `this`.
When you do that, the value of `this` defaults to the `window` object, so every time you call `createBouble()` you are updating the same object with different values.

To solve this, you can bind the `this` to some object, like so:

```
createBouble.call({}); // Assignes an empty object to 'this'
```

Or, using the `new` keyword, which assigns a new object to the `this` and also returns it (so you can avoid the `return this;`):

```
const b = new createBouble();
```

However, I think a better approach will be to avoid using the `this` and return a new object:

```
const createBouble = () => ({
  x: width * Math.random(),
  y: height * Math.random(),
  color: getColor(),
  radius: 30 + (Math.random() * 50),
});
```

Comment: Thank you, for your advice! :)

Comment: My pleasure! Glad you have found it useful